# 3DS Material -> OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3ds

How these fields in 3ds (not max) file translated to OpenGL material?

- MAT_SHIN2PCT
- MAT_SHIN3PCT
- MAT_TRANSPARENCY
- MAT_XPFALL
- MAT_REFBLUR
- MAT_SELF_ILPCT
- MAT_SHADING

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `http://www.the-labs.com/Blender/3DS-details.html` and `http://www.the-labs.com/Blender/3dsspec.html` (sorry, spam prevention won't let me post these as links). You should understand, however, that 3DS is an obsolete proprietary format, so a complete specification is not available. If possible, I'd suggest a more readily-accessible format, such as [COLLADA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA), or a custom format, in which case COLLADA is a good choice for an intermediate format.

Comment: well, 3DS wasn't chosen by me - it's something I have and need to work with. (ty)